Vue 3 + Vuetify + VTU: How to programmatically set input of v-text-field
I'm trying to write a unit test to check if my form validation works.
for that I've created a Component "Login.vue":
<script setup lang="ts">
import {ref} from "vue";

const email = ref("");
const password = ref("");
const rememberMe = ref(false);
const loginFormRef = ref<HTMLFormElement>();
const loginFormIsValid = ref(false);
const emailRules = [(value: string) => !!value && value.includes("@") || 'enter a valid email address.',];
const passwordRules = [(value: string) => !!value || 'Required.',];

const loginSubmit = () => console.log("logging in with: ", email.value, password.value, rememberMe.value);

</script>

<template>
  <v-card style="height: 400px; width: 400px">
    <v-card-title>
      Login Form
    </v-card-title>
    <v-card-item>
      <v-form data-test="login-form" ref="loginFormRef" v-model="loginFormIsValid" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
        <v-text-field data-test="login-form-text-field-email" :rules="emailRules" v-model="email" type="email" label="Email" required></v-text-field>
        <v-text-field data-test="login-form-text-field-password" :rules="passwordRules" v-model="password" type="password" label="Password" required></v-text-field>
        <v-checkbox data-test="login-form-checkbox" label="remember me" v-model="rememberMe"/>
        <v-btn data-test="login-form-button" @click="loginSubmit" :disabled="!loginFormIsValid" color="primary">Login</v-btn>
      </v-form>
    </v-card-item>
  </v-card>
</template>

This is my test:
import {afterAll, describe, expect, it} from "vitest";
import {mount} from "@vue/test-utils";
import {createVuetify} from "vuetify";
import {components, directives} from "vuetify/dist/vuetify.js";
import Login from "../../components/Login.vue";

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
})

describe("Login.vue Test suite", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Login, {plugins: [vuetify]});

    const emailTextField = wrapper.find("[data-test=login-form-text-field-email]");
    const passwordTextField = wrapper.find("[data-test=login-form-text-field-password]");
    const rememberMeCheckBox = wrapper.find("[data-test=login-form-checkbox]");
    const loginButton = wrapper.find("[data-test=login-form-button]");

    it("login form components should exist", async () => {
        expect(emailTextField.exists()).toBe(true)
        expect(passwordTextField.exists()).toBe(true)
        expect(rememberMeCheckBox.exists()).toBe(true)
        expect(loginButton.exists()).toBe(true)
    })

    it("submit button should be disabled", async () => {
        expect(loginButton.attributes('disabled')).toBe("true")
    })

    it("submit button should not be disabled", async () => {
        emailTextField.element.value = "test@test.com"; // doesn't work
        passwordTextField.element.value= "test"; // doesn't work

        await emailTextField.setValue("test@test.com"); // Error: wrapper.setValue() cannot be called on V-TEXT-FIELD
        await passwordTextField.setValue("test"); // Error: wrapper.setValue() cannot be called on V-TEXT-FIELD

        await emailTextField.find("input").trigger("input", { target: { value: "test@test.com" } }); // Error: Cannot call trigger on an empty DOMWrapper.
        await passwordTextField.find("input").trigger("input", { target: { value: "test" } }); // Error: Cannot call trigger on an empty DOMWrapper.

        emailTextField.element.setAttribute("modelvalue", "test@test.com"); // doesn't work
        passwordTextField.element.setAttribute("modelvalue", "test"); // doesn't work

        expect(loginButton.attributes('disabled')).toBe("false")
    })

    afterAll(() => wrapper.unmount())
}

Is there any way to set email and password such that the login button is no longer disabled?
This is already answered within the question, in the test code part, I show all the things I've tried that didn't work.
 emailTextField.element.value = "test@test.com"; // doesn't work
        passwordTextField.element.value= "test"; // doesn't work

        await emailTextField.setValue("test@test.com"); // Error: wrapper.setValue() cannot be called on V-TEXT-FIELD
        await passwordTextField.setValue("test"); // Error: wrapper.setValue() cannot be called on V-TEXT-FIELD

        await emailTextField.find("input").trigger("input", { target: { value: "test@test.com" } }); // Error: Cannot call trigger on an empty DOMWrapper.
        await passwordTextField.find("input").trigger("input", { target: { value: "test" } }); // Error: Cannot call trigger on an empty DOMWrapper.

        emailTextField.element.setAttribute("modelvalue", "test@test.com"); // doesn't work
        passwordTextField.element.setAttribute("modelvalue", "test"); // doesn't work

Edit
I got these to work now:
 wrapper.vm.email = "test@test.com";
 wrapper.vm.password = "test";

they practically do the same as:
 emailTextField.element.setAttribute("modelvalue", "test@test.com"); 
 passwordTextField.element.setAttribute("modelvalue", "test"); 

When I use console.log(wrapper.html()), I get:
<v-card style="height: 400px; width: 400px;">
  <v-card-title> Login Form </v-card-title>
  <v-card-item>
    <v-form data-test="login-form" modelvalue="false" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
      <v-text-field data-test="login-form-text-field-email" rules="(value) => !!value && value.includes(" @") || "enter a valid email address."" type=" email" label="Email" required="" modelvalue="test@test.com"></v-text-field>
      <v-text-field data-test="login-form-text-field-password" rules="(value) => !!value || " Required."" type="password" label="Password" required="" modelvalue="test"></v-text-field>
      <v-checkbox data-test="login-form-checkbox" label="remember me" modelvalue="false"></v-checkbox>
      <v-btn data-test="login-form-button" disabled="true" color="primary">Login</v-btn>
    </v-form>
  </v-card-item>
</v-card>

So now the Values are Set properly, but the disabled-property of the Button doesn't update.
I also tried:
await wrapper.$nexttick() without any success.

setValue works on VueWrapper component, so when finding the element use wrapper.findComponent('[data-test=login-form-text-field-email]') and then use setValue on the same.

For that I get Error: Cannot call setValue on an empty VueWrapper.

It seems like your test env is not setup correctly, because wrapper.html() shows Vuetify components rather than plain HTML ones.
Ensure that you have this set in your vite.config.js:
export default defineConfig({
//...
test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    server: {
      deps: {
        inline: ['vuetify'],
      },
    },
  }
//...
}

Also, rather than passing { plugins: [vuetify] } to the mount function, try { global: { plugins: [vuetify] } } as described here.
If you run into trouble with transition-group-stubs hiding your components, add
import { config } from "@vue/test-utils";

config.global.stubs.transition = false;
config.global.stubs['transition-group'] = false;

to your test file.
I imagine triggering an input event should work, when all components render correctly.
